# Can't get a user input variable to pass into the rest of script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a stop watch to show how much people get paid per x time they work. I can't get the user to input their salary and then pass this number along to the script. I keep getting NaN as a result. Its easy to use a 'prompt' function, but I would prefer some input on the page.

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
body {
    background: #0e415f;
    min-width:800px;
    max-width:2400px;
    font-family: Omnes, Myriad Pro, arial, Helvetica;
    color: #f1a400;}

.header {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.clock {
    border: 3px solid #f1a400 double;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: double;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 20 auto;    

    font-size: 10em;
    text-align:center;}

.money {
    border: 3px solid #f1a400 double;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: double;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 20 auto;

    font-size: 10em;
    text-align:center;}

.buttons {
    width: 350px; 
    margin: 20 auto;}   

.button_style{
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin: 0 .3em;
    background: #f1a400;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0;}
</style>



<script type="text/javascript">
function getSalary()
      {
        var salaryAm = document.getElementById("salaries");
        var salary = salaryAm.value;}


var seconds=-1.0; /* To start clock at 0 seconds */
var min=0;
var time;
var secPay = Number(salary)/(52*40*60*60); /* Weeks * Hours * Minutes * Seconds */
var timerPay = 0; 

function timer(){
        seconds++;       

        if(seconds>59){
                min++;
                document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=padTimer(min);
                seconds=0;}

        document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=padTimer(seconds);    
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=parseFloat(secPay*timerPay++).toFixed(2);
        };

function padTimer(x) {
    if (x<=9) { x = ("0"+x); }
    return x;}

function start(){
    time=setInterval(timer, 1000);
    timer;}


function pause() { 
    clearInterval(time);
    seconds--;
    timerPay--;};

function reset(){
    seconds=-1.0;
    timerPay=0;
    time=0;
    if (min !=0){
        min=0;}};
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <input id="salaries" type="text">

<div class="header"><img src="breakcalc.png"></div>

<div class="clock">
    <span id="mins" >00</span>:<span id="secs">00</span><br>
</div>

<div class="money">
    <span>$ </span><span id="money">0.00</span>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" id="button" onclick="start()" ondblclick="return false;"><button class="button_style">Start</button></a>
    <a href="#" id="button" onclick="pause()"><button class="button_style">Stop</button></a>
    <a href="#" id="button" onclick="reset()"><button class="button_style">Reset</button></a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll get answers faster if you put this on jsfiddle then link it here. Save others time.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to but can't login. They said there some issue right now w, Spambots or something.

Comment: You have a working `getSalary` function, but it doesn't return anything, and it's never called...

Comment: @user2687642 if jsfiddle isn't working then plnkr.co is a good alternative (might be a better one actually)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables as global so that you can access them and then you need to call the `getSalary()` method in order to set the salary from input field into the variable.

Also, check the number using `isNaN()` method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var salary;
var seconds=-1.0; /* To start clock at 0 seconds */
var min=0;
var time;
var secPay;
var timerPay = 0; 


// This method will set the salary variable and then return true if the salary is a number.
function getSalary() {
        var salaryAm = document.getElementById("salaries");
        salary = salaryAm.value;
        secPay = Number(salary)/(52*40*60*60); /* Weeks * Hours * Minutes * Seconds */

         return !isNaN(secPay);
 }


function timer(){
        seconds++;       

        if(seconds>59){
                min++;
                document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=padTimer(min);
                seconds=0;}

        document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=padTimer(seconds);    
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=parseFloat(secPay*timerPay++).toFixed(2);
        };

function padTimer(x) {
    if (x<=9) { x = ("0"+x); }
    return x;}

function start(){
    if (getSalary()) {
        time=setInterval(timer, 1000);
        timer;
    } else {
        alert("please check input");
    } 
  }


function pause() { 
    clearInterval(time);
    seconds--;
    timerPay--;};

function reset(){
    seconds=-1.0;
    timerPay=0;
    time=0;
    if (min !=0){
        min=0;}
    document.getElementById("salaries").value = "";//reset input
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to make salery a global variable then set it in with call to your `getSalery()` function in the `start()` function. Also parseFloat the value from the input.

```
function getSalary()
      {
        var salaryAm = document.getElementById("salaries");
        salary = parseFloat(salaryAm.value);}


var seconds=-1.0; /* To start clock at 0 seconds */
var min=0;
var time;
var secPay = Number(salary)/(52*40*60*60); /* Weeks * Hours * Minutes * Seconds */
var timerPay = 0; 
var salary = 0.0;

function timer(){
        seconds++;       

        if(seconds>59){
                min++;
                document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=padTimer(min);
                seconds=0;}

        document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=padTimer(seconds);    
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=parseFloat(secPay*timerPay++).toFixed(2);
        };

function padTimer(x) {
    if (x<=9) { x = ("0"+x); }
    return x;}

function start(){
    time=setInterval(timer, 1000);
getSalary()
    timer;}


function pause() { 
    clearInterval(time);
    seconds--;
    timerPay--;};

function reset(){
    seconds=-1.0;
    timerPay=0;
    time=0;
    if (min !=0){
        min=0;}};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var secPay = Number(salary)/(52*40*60*60); /* Weeks * Hours * Minutes * Seconds
```

At the time this var is set, `salary` is `NaN` AND it is only within your function, not global. Also, you're never calling the `getSalary()`.
I suggest `onclick="getSalary();start()"`

Here is the working script:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
body {
    background: #0e415f;
    min-width:800px;
    max-width:2400px;
    font-family: Omnes, Myriad Pro, arial, Helvetica;
    color: #f1a400;}

.header {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.clock {
    border: 3px solid #f1a400 double;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: double;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 20 auto;    

    font-size: 10em;
    text-align:center;}

.money {
    border: 3px solid #f1a400 double;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: double;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 20 auto;

    font-size: 10em;
    text-align:center;}

.buttons {
    width: 350px; 
    margin: 20 auto;}   

.button_style{
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin: 0 .3em;
    background: #f1a400;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0;}
</style>



<script type="text/javascript">
var salary;
var secPay;
function getSalary()
      {
        salary = Number(document.getElementById("salaries").value);
        secPay = salary /(52*40*60*60); /* Weeks * Hours * Minutes * Seconds */

        }


var seconds=-1.0; /* To start clock at 0 seconds */
var min=0;
var time;
var timerPay = 0; 
alert 
function timer(){
        seconds++;       

        if(seconds>59){
                min++;
                document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=padTimer(min);
                seconds=0;}

        document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=padTimer(seconds);    
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=parseFloat(secPay*timerPay++).toFixed(2);
        };

function padTimer(x) {
    if (x<=9) { x = ("0"+x); }
    return x;}

function start(){
    time=setInterval(timer, 1000);
    timer;}


function pause() { 
    clearInterval(time);
    seconds--;
    timerPay--;};

function reset(){
    seconds=-1.0;
    timerPay=0;
    time=0;
    if (min !=0){
        min=0;}};
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <input id="salaries" type="text">

<div class="header"><img src="breakcalc.png"></div>

<div class="clock">
    <span id="mins" >00</span>:<span id="secs">00</span><br>
</div>

<div class="money">
    <span>$ </span><span id="money">0.00</span>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" id="button" onclick="getSalary();start()" ondblclick="return false;"><button class="button_style">Start</button></a>
    <a href="#" id="button" onclick="pause()"><button class="button_style">Stop</button></a>
    <a href="#" id="button" onclick="reset()"><button class="button_style">Reset</button></a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also you need to disable the start button once clicked because as it is you can keep clicking it and starting multiple intervals that speed up the clock.